# Как вставить значение в FormData

Tags: javascript

Не получается вставить значение `grecaptcha.getResponse()` в `FormData()` я использовал метод `append()` из интерфейса `FormData`, я пробовал по разному объявлять переменную с Jquery и без, использовать похожие методы, но ничего не выходит выдает одну и туже ошибку:

```
...append is not a function
```

В чем дело, как мне лучше вставить это значение в FormData, используя только JavaScript?

Пример кода:

```js
function submitFormAjax() {

  let captcha = grecaptcha.getResponse();

  if (captcha.length) {

    let xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ?
      new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
        alert(this.responseText);
    }

    let data = new URLSearchParams(Array.from(new FormData(document.querySelector('#support')))).toString();

    data.append('g-recaptcha-response', captcha);

    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'https://www.archsupport.ru/post-email.php', true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(data);
  }

  grecaptcha.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('#support'));
formData.append('g-recaptcha-response', captcha);

let data = new URLSearchParams(Array.from(formData)).toString();
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я вроде понял!  Я преобразовал массив formdata в строку раньше времени, поэтому ничего не работало? Все так?

Comment: @ПоляковРоман Да, так.

Comment: Ну я и тормоз, спасибо(